# How to keep track of the collision and total probe length in the set item function of my hash table implementation in python?

Tags: python, hashtable

Hi I'm new to Python and I implemented a hash table using linear probing to resolve collisions. If two keys hash to the same position then the collision occurs once only and the subsequent tries to resolve it is the probe length.  I modified my set item function to keep track of the number of collisions and the probe length.But I don't know how to get the collisions and probe length from the function  because set item is called like this: my_table["Julian"] = "FIT1008" ?

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    position = self.hash_value(key)
    sameKeyCollision=False
    for _ in range(self.table_size):
        if self.array[position] is None:#found empty slot, collision resolve
            self.array[position] = (key, value)
            self.count += 1
            sameKeyCollision=False


            return
        elif self.array[position][0] == key:#found key
            self.array[position] = (key, value)#update value, no collision
            return
        elif self.array[position][0] !=key and sameKeyCollision==False:#not found try next,first time collision
            position = (position+1) % self.table_size
            self.totalProbeLength+=1
            self.collision+=1
            sameKeyCollision=True
        elif self.array[position][0] !=key and sameKeyCollision==True:#probing
            position = (position+1) % self.table_size
            self.totalProbeLength+=1
    raise ValueError("Table is Full!")
```

This is my constructor:

```
 def __init__(self, size=30):
    self.count = 0
    self.table_size = size
    self.array = build_array(self.table_size)
    self.collision=0
    self.totalProbeLength=0
```

I haven't tested my code because I don't know how to get the probeLength and collision from my set item function, so I apologise for any errors and please point them out.Thanks!

EDIT:Okay I just realised I can declare a class variable then access it directly like self.collision and self.totalProbeLength.However, they both keep returning 0?

Comment: Update your code with the new changes so folks can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: I updated the code